# Icons of different layers cover each other in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, layers, icon

I have converted 6 KML files (including a set of points) into 6 layers by ArcMap 10. For points in each layer, I have considered a special icon with a specific color. I also decreased the size of icons as much as possible. But the icons of different layers cover each other and the picture is not desirable enough to be inserted in an article.

Is there any way to convert the icons into transparent ones?